# git clone not working in docker file

Tags: java, docker

```
FROM java:8

RUN apt-get -y install git

RUN git clone https://username:password@github.com/<repo> C:/Users/USER/Desktop/gitFolder

COPY C:/Users/USER/Desktop/gitFolder /var/www/java  

WORKDIR /var/www/java  

RUN javac helloWorld.java

CMD ["java", "helloWorld"]
```

I am a beginner in docker and these are  the docker commands i am following to run a javacode which is taken from github.Even though it is not giving any error during cloning,nothing is getting cloned in the gitFolder.

Comment: Why is there a local path in your github url?

Comment: Remember that anyone who has your image can run `docker history` and see the full text of commands run during the build sequence.  You're better off cloning the repository outside the Dockerfile; in fact, it's quite common to check the Dockerfile into the root directory of the repository.

Answer (score 4):

the path C:/Users/USER/Desktop/gitFolder is inexistent in your docker container.

```
RUN apt-get -y install git
RUN git clone https://username:password@github.com/<repo> C:/Users/USER/Desktop/gitFolder
```

you could do this

```
FROM java:8

RUN apt-get -y install git

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/java

WORKDIR /var/www/java

RUN git clone https://github.com/beeradb/kubectl-slackbot.git
...
```